# Linq-to-Sql - Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8, datacontext

While the following works when the Students collection is populated from in memory sample data, I get a `System.NotSupportedException` when querying the database. I'm working on a WindowsPhone 8 project.

```
List<CustomGrouping<Student>> groupings =
    (from student in dataContext.Students
        orderby student.FirstName
        orderby student.LastName         
    group student by Char.ToLower(student.FirstName.First()) into grouping        
    select new CustomGrouping<Student>(
        grouping.Key, grouping.AsEnumerable())).ToList();
```

Why does it happen with the database query and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`student.FirstName.First()` is not supported. Try:

```
student.FirstName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()
```

or:

```
student.FirstName[0].ToLower()
```

instead

Comment: I need a char not a string. The first suggestion returns a string and `char.ToLower(student.FirstName[0])` still throws a `NotSupportedException` Method 'Char ToLower(Char)' has no supported translation to SQL. The second suggestion is not how the extension method is implemented.

Comment: @Pantelis frankly, tough; use the first version, and change from a string-of-length-1 to a `char` **after** you have done the database query. LINQ-to-SQL wants to use `string`